# airflow docker compose cannot access webserver

Tags: docker-compose, webserver, airflow

My problem

I am trying to use two docker-compose.yml files (each in separate directories) on the same host machine, one for Airflow and the other for another application, both had a container that mapped the host port 8080 to container port 8080. So I changed the Airflow docker-compose.yml file to map host port 50309 to container port 8080, after doing this I am no longer able to access the webserver from my browser. I am using the URL indicated in the [official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) http://localhost:8080

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Airflow docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.0}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  #added working directory and scripts folder 6-26-2021 CP
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./scripts:\Users\courtney\Desktop\airflow\scripts
    - ./wrk:\Users\courtney\Desktop\airflow\wrk 
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    #changed from default of 8080 because of clash with baton docker services 6-26-2021 CP
    ports:
      - 50309:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

#snapshot of other application docker-compose.yml specific to host port 8080

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: redacted.redacted.com/docker/postgres:11.3
    ports:
      - 11101:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
    networks:
      - tempo

  keycloak:
    image: redacted.git.redacted.com/redacted/redacted-server/keycloak:${TEMPO_VERSION:-develop}
    container_name: my_keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME: redacted
      KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME: redacted
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:9080/auth
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: db
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
    networks:
      - tempo
    depends_on:
      - db
  server:
    image: registry.git.aredacted.com/redacted/redacted-server/server:${TEMPO_VERSION:-develop}
    command: [ "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005", "conf/single.conf" ]
    environment:
      AKKA_PARALLELISM_MAX: "2"
      DB_THREADPOOL_SIZE: "4"
      UNSAFE_ENABLED: "true"
      DOCKER_BIND_HOST_ROOT: "${BIND_ROOT}"
      DOCKER_BIND_CONTAINER_ROOT: "/var/lib/tempo2"
      MESSAGING_HOST: "server"

      PUBSUB_TYPE: inmem

      TEMPOJOBS_DOCKER_TAG: registry.git.redacted.com/redacted/redacted-server/redacted:${TEMPO_VERSION:-develop}

      NUM_WORKER: 1
      ASSET_CACHE_SIZE: 500M
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - "${BIND_ROOT}:/var/lib/tempo2"
    ports:
      - 2551:2551 # akka port
      - 8080:8080 # application http port
      - 8081:8081 # executor http port
      - 5005:5005 # debug port
    networks:
      - tempo
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  tempo:
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that because I changed my local host value to 50309 that this is the number that should replace 8080 in my URL  noob.